# How to add a link to this code

Tags: html

I would like to add a link to this code so people can download some posts from my blog.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webstorage_local_clickcount

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

a link can be added by creating an a tag like this:

```
<a href="downloadlink">  put piece to click here  </a>
```

the download link can be an external download link although, 
the file location should also work.

Comment: Anywhere in your body basicly. Just put the <button> tags between the <a> tags and it should work. This would look like this: <a href=“link”><button blablabla>click to download</button></a>